# Which Huggingface model is best suited for translation related multi-task fine-tuning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

There are some multi-task models with translations on Huggingface model lists, e.g.

- https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/flan-t5

  - a mixture of tasks
- https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/nllb

  - translation + summarization (and implicitly language identification)
- https://huggingface.co/bigscience/bloomz

  - various tasks

Given some data that has of feature extraction or text generation + translation,

[in]:

```
[INFO] An orphaned boy enrolls in a school of wizardry, where he learns the truth about himself, his family and the terrible evil that haunts the magical world.

[TRANSLATE] [FR] An orphaned boy enrolls in a school of wizardry, where he learns the truth about himself, his family and the terrible evil that haunts the magical world.
```

[out]:

```
Chris Columbus [DIRECTOR] JK Rowling, Steve Kloves [WRITER] Daniel Radcliffe, Rupert Grint, Richard Harris [STARS]

Un garçon orphelin s'inscrit dans une école de sorcellerie, où il apprend la vérité sur lui-même, sa famille et le terrible mal qui hante le monde magique.
```

#### Is there any good suggestions on models on Huggingface to start tuning from?

---

P/S: Asking here instead of stackoverflow or datascience stackexchange because this question would be closed since it's asking for "recommendations"/"suggestions"